# How to return to a specified code line in Android Studio?

Tags: android, line

How to return to a certain line when writing codes;
for example:

```
if (example == 0)
{go to line 114}
```

or

```
if (example == 1)
{repeat line 114 to 123}
```

I know about `do` and `while`, and `if` statement, but because my codes are very long, if I use `if` statement, my codes will be very long.
I am making a quiz. I want to show them random, and if user clicked the correct answer, next question will be shown.
I used

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
switch (i1) {
case 0: {
question 1
}
break;
}
case 1: {
question 2
}
break;
}
........
```

but it takes too space; so I thought maybe it is better to repeat some questions.
I hope I have been able to express my mean.

Comment: Java is not BASIC.

Comment: May be a method call?

Comment: No `goto` :p Use functions.

Comment: Put the lines you want to execute in a `method`, and call this method when required.

Comment: http://numod.ins.uni-bonn.de/grape/MANUAL/manual/node91.html explains the difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of no prior research.

Comment: What is the reason for you to go to a particular line number..?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that you are very new to Java. As was pointed out above, Java is different from Basic. I think you might benefit from finding a good book or course on Android programming. The things you apparently try to do, can be done using methods, `while` loops and proper use of `if`-`else` blocks. A good book or course will cover these. Good luck!

Comment: You should pass through some basic Java training before you continue

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do something like that when you're inside a loop using the [labeled continue statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

But it's something I've never seen in practice. As others said, if you need to do something, then this something should be in a function that you call.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode line numbers simply because they will always change when adding code. For example, to use a method you may need to import it which will add 1 line to the code.

Instead, create your own methods and call them whenever you need them.